# Play services ads and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission

Tags: android, google-play-services, androidx

In our Android app, I use `play-services-ads`. I noticed that it adds [`android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) in the manifest, which shows as "run at startup" permission at the Play Store. This permission results to negative reviews by some users.

`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` is added by [androidx.work](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/package-summary) which `play-services-ads` depends on.

Is it a good idea to remove this from the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a good idea, from Android documentation:

> WorkManager uses the following permissions: ..
> `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` to listen to reboots and
> reschedule work properly.

At some point Google Play services is using the workmanager for it's tasks, maybe try to visually disclosure the reason why you are using that permission on the app itself and the play store's app long description.

**Example**: This is the disclosure for using location in the background, in your case it won't ask for runtime permission, but i'm showing this just for the disclosure.

[image]